# Prove that $v(n)\leq v(2^{n}-1)$ where $v(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to solve this problem in my book

> Prove that $v(n)\leq v(2^{n}-1)$ where $v(n)$ is the number of
>   positive divisors of $n$

but I am stuck. I honestly have no idea how to even proceed with this. Please help.

Comment: This is a nice little problem. My hint is to consider the polynomial $X^n-1$ instead of the number $2^n-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$ is an integer and $k$ is a positive integer, the algebraic identity
$$x^k-1=(x-1)(x^{k-1}+\cdots + 1)$$
yields $(x-1){\,\mid\,}(x^k-1)$.

Thus, if $a$ is a positive integer divisor of $n$, then letting $b=n/a$, we get
$$2^n-1=2^{ab}-1=(2^a)^b-1$$
hence $(2^a-1){\,\mid\,}(2^n-1)$.

Thus for each positive integer divisor $a$ of $n$, we have the positive integer divisor $2^a-1$ of $2^n-1$, and no two such factors $2^a-1$ of $2^n-1$ are equal.

It follows that $2^n-1$ has at least as many positive integer divisors as does $n$.